# Fetching PDO - $handler vs $stmt?

Tags: php, pdo

I am VERY new to PHP / PDO, so please be gentle...

I am trying to enter code into my database and then fetch it into a webpage. I am able to do the first but am having difficulty displaying it. I am wondering if it's because i'm trying to combine $stmt and $handler together?

This is my code for entering the information into the database:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO survey (storename, receipt, date_visit)
    VALUES (:storename, :receipt, :date_visit)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':storename', $storename);
    $stmt->bindParam(':receipt', $receipt);
    $stmt->bindParam(':date_visit', $date_visit);

    // insert a row
    $storename = $_POST['storename'];
    $receipt = $_POST['receipt'];
    $date_visit = $_POST['date_visit'];

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

It works perfectly.

This is my code for fetching information from my database.

```
<?php

try {
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'test', 'test');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATRR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
  }

class SurveyEntry {
    public $id, $storename, $receipt, $date_visited,
        $entry;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->entry = "{$this->storename} posted: {$this->receipt}";
    }
}

$query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM survey');
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'SurveyEntry');
while($r = $query->fetch()) {
    echo $r->entry, '<br>';
}

?>
```

I can confirm that it connects correctly, but I can't get it to display any information. I'm wondering if it's something to do with the difference in $stmt and $handler that i'm using? I've been following tutorials online and have quite possibly mixed 2 tutorials together to try and achieve what i'm looking for.

UPDATE:

I managed to get it to work by updating how I called from the database:

```
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "test";

$user = "test";
$password = "test";

$handler = new PDO( "mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$host" , $user , $password );
```

Comment: You misspelled `query` in `$handler->guery`. You have a `g` instead of `q`.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you name the variables. You can call it `$stmt` in one script and `$handler` in another script, they don't have to match.

Comment: Oops, you're right. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be the problem though as it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Barmar That's good to know, thank you. Any idea why it doesn't work though?

Comment: Make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` enabled. Do you get any notices or errors?

Comment: I have added this, but don't get any errors. The page is just blank.

Comment: I've never used `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` myself, but from what I've read, it looks like you're using it correctly. Is it printing anything at all?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. My page is just blank. I checked the connection by changing the dbname and it came back with an error. So I know it's connecting okay, it's just not pulling the information for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure there's something in the table? Put `echo "before<br>";` and `echo "after<br>";` before and after the `while` loop to make sure it's getting there.

Comment: I managed to fix it. I think there was  a problem with how I was calling my database. I'll update my answer.

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether you use literals or variables when call `new PDO`. You must have changed something else.

Comment: Nope, this was the only thing. Odd. Maybe I had a username or something wrong. I did also remove the $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATRR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); section down to the class. Maybe this was the problem?

Comment: No, that shouldn't be a problem, I strongly recommend you keep that option. You probably had a typo somewhere and fixed it when you edited.

Comment: Figured it out! I had 'ATRR_ERRMODE' instead of 'ATTR' (2 r's, not 2 t's). Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Yep, I see it now. Like I said, it was just a typo somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - I had 'ATRR_ERRMODE' instead of 'ATTR_ERRMODE' (typo)

Answer (score 0):

how are you?

You should try to fix it:

1- Two different connections:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);


$handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'test', 'test');
```